# Create a ViewController that shows on First Launch Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

SO I am creating an iOS app that involves allowing the user to be able to receive push notifications. I already have the following code in my appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
if ([application     respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];


}
```

So far so good, however, i would like to create an initial view controller that only shows on first launch, it will hopefully explain and justify to the user why it need the ability to send the user push notifications, they can then press continue and it will ask them by executing the code above. This would hopefully only happen on the first launch. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but why did you tag Swift if your code is Obj-C?

Comment: Cause if someone gives an answer for swift I'll work it out myself in C!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    BOOL userHasOnboarded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isFirstTime"];

    if (userHasOnboarded) {
        [self setupNormalRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    else {
        self.window.rootViewController = [self PushExplanation];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}



- (void)setupNormalRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIViewController *mainVC = [UIViewController new];
    mainVC.title = @"Home View Controller";

    if (animated) {
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
        } completion:nil];
    }

    else {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
    }
}
```

In your PushExplanation method you can show the UIviewController you want to show once and then in the same UIViewController you can ask for Push Notifications like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial.

Add a boolean flag haveDisplayedFirstVC to NSUserDefaults. Read it at startup. If it's false, you need to display your first time VC.

In that case, if you're using storyboards, use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to load a view controller from your storyboard. If you're using nibs, use `initWithNibName:bundle:`

Once you've created and configured the view controller, display it on top of your standard interface's VC using `presentViewController:animated:completion:' but with animated = NO. That way it will appear on top of your normal interface as the app starts up. (Or animate it onto the screen, whichever you prefer.)

Comment: That's fine, but how do I then make it ask for notification permission when the button is pressed rather than in the didFinishLaunching?

Answer (score 0):

Add the status (Bool) in **NSUserDefault** and Firsttime check if the key is there or not . 
If there is no value,then display your initial viewcontroller and change the status to yes(probably).
Next time normal page will load.